# angular typescript wait for method to complete not working

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

I am modifying an angular8 typescript class. I want to wait for a method to complete before implementing further logic. Please find my code below:

```
  aync processData() {
    await test();
    console.log('-- after async call --);
  }

  async test() {
    if (this.data && this.data.itemData) {
      this.data.itemData.map(async (itemData) => {
        await this.itemCrudService.getItemDataById(itemData.itemId)
        .subscribe((response) => {
          console.log('response', response);
        })
      })
    }
  }
```

Here, I want to wait for `test()` method to prepare item data (some global array) to be further used in `processData()` method.

Please note that it also involves a http call to retrieve item data by `itemId`.

But the `console.log` after the test method call is getting called before test method is finished.

Comment: should'nt it be this? ```async processData() {```
We can await inside an async function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pipe async like that, because there are nested async calls. So you are waiting for the **call** to finish, not for the execution to finish.

First: you should not use global variables in such situations because you are asking for lots of bugs down the road, when you forget about the order of things.

Instead, you should use proper RxJs operators to correctly express your semantics. Here, I guess you want something like:

```js
const dataPipes = ....map(itemData => this.itemCrudService.get...());
// Now, you create a new observable with all results:
const allValues = forkJoin(dataPipes);
// Now, you process all values when they arrive:
allValues.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(dataArray => { ...here you have all data... });
```

The `pipe(take(1))` is to avoid unsubscribing since you just wait for a response. You could also do the following if you prefer Promise:

```js
allValues.toPromise().then(dataArray => { ...here you have all data... });
```

You can have more information about all the possible operators & usage in the [official docs](https://rxjs.dev), and samples on [learnrxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io).

Comment: can there be a simpler solution to just return an array of observable ?

Comment: Not that I think of, you really need to wait for all requests to finish and return - this necessarily introduces some work. The code I gave is 3 lines long, I guess you can't do much shorter :)